# Modifying models without breaking Django Flow

Tags: python, django, models, ddl

I'm still somewhat new to the whole django-thing with defining models in `Models.py`

My question is, my db schema is still somewhat rough and I have been changing things the past few days before committing with `syncdb` command, is it unsafe to basically use a program like *MySql Workbench* or *Sequel Pro* and run DDL code to alter database table info: for instance changing a field to a CHAR() or adding new columns through an *external* interface.

Will django become completely confused? (Since the DDL wasn't explicitly declared in models.py beforehand and `syncdb` run?)

If so, what is a better approach?

I still have yet to find one.

Thank you for all the information you can give me.

Comment: You can use django south for db migrations (http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or manually edit table definitions in db.

Comment: So its "OK" to modify with a 3rd-party program like Mysql Workbench or  Sequel Pro? How does Django deal with 3rd-party program changing db ddl ?

Comment: @Asterisk - if you could explain in an answer - would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do are named `migrations`,  you can use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) this one is very helpful